# underscore.js toArray function for comma delineated values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, underscore.js

I have a multiselect menu that returns value in this format:

`ATL,AZ,BAL,BUF`

I need to convert the values to an array of strings, something that would look like this:

`["ATL", "AZ" , "BAL", "BUF"]`

I am using the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#toArray) `_.toArray` function, but am getting this result:

`["A", "T", "L", "A", "Z", "B", "A", "L", "B", "U", "F"]`

Does anyone know how I can create an array of strings from the `ATL,AZ,BAL,BUF`string? I'm not tied to underscore.js, but thought I should be able to do it with that library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use native [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var a="ATL,AZ,BAL,BUF"
a.split(',')
["ATL", "AZ", "BAL", "BUF"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the [split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

`'ATL,AZ,BAL,BUF'.split(',');`